# How to log stored procedure names to log file using log4j xml

Tags: java, log4j

In my java application we are calling lot of oracle Stored procedures. I would like to log stored procedure names into a log file using log4j.

Lot tried in google, but did not found solution.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate or MyBatis?

Answer (score 0):

Check [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/log4jdbc/). It is a Java JDBC driver that can log SQL and/or JDBC calls (and optionally SQL timing information) for other JDBC drivers using the Simple Logging Facade For Java (SLF4J) logging system.

Comment: Using hibernate with spring. Calling stored procedures using jdbc callablestatement. We just want to log stored proc name when it fired like how we logging hibernate sql i.e. org.hibernate.SQL where we set show_sql = true.